# 504 Gateway Time-out error - upstream timed out while reading response header

Tags: nginx

I upgraded nginx 1.11 and PHP 7.1 on my vagrant running Ubuntu 14.04, to nginx 1.13.1 and PHP 7.2.

Both services are confirmed running.

Now when I try to access any `example.test` sites, nothing happens. The browser just waits to load indefinitely until eventually I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` error and this shows in ``:

```
2018/01/14 23:51:55 [error] 3058#3058: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: example.test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.10.10"
```

Visiting `example.test` does not work and neither does `192.168.10.10` which is what it maps to in my host.

In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I see only this:

```
2018/01/14 23:41:55 [notice] 3052#3052: signal process started
```

In `/var/log/nginx/example.test-access.log` I see only this:

```
192.168.10.1 - - [14/Jan/2018:23:42:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.test` conf file contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.test;
    root "/home/vagrant/Projects/example.test/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.test-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.test-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.test.key;
}
```

What could be causing the hangup here?

Comment: maybe you can try to move 'include fastcgi_params;' after 'fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;' then test again

Comment: So where is your php-fpm configuration?

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono moving it did not fix it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton where can I find which php-fpm ini is in use? When I do `php -i` I only see the 7.0 cli ini, which is not helpful.

Comment: you can use `php --ini` to know where your php.ini

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono that still gives me the CLI edition at `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`